# "loaded the "XXX" nib but the view outlet was not set." - again

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, nib

Firstly I have inspected all of the other questions on this topic: the answers provided seem to be:

1. make sure you set the file's owner to your custom view controller class (which I have done)
2. make sure you have a referencing outlet from the view to the file's owner (which I have)

My code is compiled to a static library, and I export the .a file and xib file.
My example app that uses it includes the xib in its bundle ("copy bundle resources" in build phase)

In my library code I have a function in a separate UIViewContoller subclass to create the view controller from the nib:

```
- (void) presentCustomController
{
  self.vCtrl = [[CustomController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomController" bundle:nil];
  ...
}
```

When I run the example app, I inspect the _view member of self.vCtrl, and it is 0x0000, and of course this is what causes the exception in the posting title.
My understanding was that the view to which that member points was 'auto generated' from the xib file, and it's children were the controls that I have put in it (buttons etc). 
What part of my understanding has fallen down? Is the problem related to the fact that it is  in a static library?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: cmd + k to clean the project and re-run?

Comment: You can shorten this to `[[CustomController alloc] init]` it will pick the nib automatically.

Comment: I don't know if xcode is capable of cleaning an XXX project

Comment: That is absolutely hilarious @Ben

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are 100% that you connected your View to the File's Owner then I suggest you do the following:

1. Clean the project (`cmd+shift+K`) or Clean Build Folder if you prefer (`cmd+shift+alt+K`)
2. Quit Xcode
3. Restart Xcode

That should fix it hopefully.

Comment: Thank you. I quit Xcode, manually removed all intermediate files, deleted all exported xib files so I knew I was in a 'really clean' state. Rebuilding all and checking the exported xib manually (yes I'm paranoid) in the example app bundle confirmed the connection, and when I ran it, it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks!  Struggled for a while with this.  Made no sense to me, but cleaning and restarting Xcode did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

Do you have multiple targets?

> 1. make sure you set the file's owner to your custom view controller class (which I have done)

I have come across a similar issue where I thought that I was setting the file's owner's custom class, however, IB was not actually setting it.  Open the XIB as its raw xml and search for the custom class name.

For me it was because the .m of the view controller was not included for my specific target.  To fix this check all the boxes in the target membership pane.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - in fact I did open the xib as raw and checked that too, but forgot to state that in my original question. Answer above solved the problem - a tools issue not a programmatic one.